# WPF TreeView C# MVVM get parent when instance is referenced by multiple collections

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Given data structure that follows this pattern

```
class Top
{
    string Header { get; set; }
    ObservableCollection<Middle> Children { get; set; }
}

class Middle
{
    string Header { get; set; }
    ObservableCollection<Bottom> Children { get; set; }
}

class Bottom
{
    string Header { get; set; }
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

If `Top` contains two different instances of `Middle` and both of those contain the same instance of `Bottom`, how can I determine the parent of the selected item? I'd like to remove the `Bottom` from the selected `Middle`, but not both.

The expected behavior when the items are linked is that changes to either one will always update the other. Referencing the same instance in both collections creates the intended behavior in the TreeView right now.

Can the visual tree helper be used from the ViewModel for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I determine the parent of the selected item?

May be by applying the *Parent* property in it? But then you won't be able to have the same instance of Bottom class since their parents will be different.

```
class Bottom
{
    Middle Parent { get; set; }
    string Header { get; set; }
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

I would recommend you to have a separate ViewModel with the *Parent* property for every TreeView item in the TreeView. Then you could inject the same instance of *BottomModel* into separate *BottomViewModel*s (which have their corresponding parents). In this case both *BottomViewModel*s will expose the same data from *BottomModel* but you could remove them independently.

There is another (probably clearer and more proper) approach where you can have different instances of Bottom class (whatever Model or ViewModel) with *Parent* property and you keep them linked and in sync with something like Event Aggregator.

Also, here is a pretty comprehensive tutorial how to work with a TreeView in WPF/MVVM:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Comment: instead of having single parent, He can maintain collection for holding parents and later he can decide which one should last.. right?

Comment: @WPFUser If each location has a separate instance then each will only have one parent.

Answer (score 0):

Using the helper class in this blog

https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the first ancester of specified type
/// </summary>
public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject current)
where T : DependencyObject
{
    current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);

    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current is T)
        {
            return (T)current;
        }
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    };
    return null;
}
```

Then in the DataTemplate `PreviewMouseRightButtonUp` and `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` for the content control and add the following code

```
var current = VisualTreeHelpers.FindAncestor<TreeViewItem>(sender as UIElement);
var parent = VisualTreeHelpers.FindAncestor<TreeViewItem>(current);
var parentVM = parent.DataContext as ITreeNode;
(DataContext as NavigationViewModel).SelectedParent = parentVM;
```

`ITreeNode` defines a method `RemoveChild(ITreeNode)` and all of the objects in my tree implement `ITreeNode`.

When removing an item call `MainViewModel.inst.Navigation.RemoveChild(child);`

The key to this solution is that the code behind is able to differentiate between TreeViewItems that are created by the same instance of Bottom.

Comment: The event handler is added for left and right because the property might be used on context menu or ribbon